# Triggering the click event of inner anchor on click of outer div is going in infinite loop?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to click on outer element and want to trigger the click event of child element to see the parent child click event relationship. Here is my code :-

```
  <div id="id1">DIV1
    <a href="#" id="id2">DIV2</a>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).off('click', 'a#id2');
    $(document).on('click', 'a#id2', function(){
        alert('div2 clicked');
    });

    $(document).off('click', 'div#id1');
    $(document).on('click', 'div#id1', function(){
        alert($('div#id1').find('a').attr('id'));
        $('div#id1').find('a').trigger('click');
    });
    </script>
```

But it is going in infinite loop.
Could you please help me on this ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your click event `bubbles` through its parents. If you do not want an event to bubble to the clicked element's parents, you need to stop it from happening.

http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

These reads should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 3):

This infinite loop is due to **event bubbling** - you can stop event bubbling using [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```js
$(document).off('click', 'a#id2');
    $(document).on('click', 'a#id2', function(event){
        alert('div2 clicked');
         event.stopPropagation(); // STOP EVENT BUBBLING
    });

    $(document).off('click', 'div#id1');
    $(document).on('click', 'div#id1', function(event){
        alert($('div#id1').find('a').attr('id'));
        $('div#id1').find('a').trigger('click');
      //  event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">DIV1
    <a href="#" id="id2">DIV2</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).off('click', 'a#id2');
    $(document).on('click', 'a#id2', function(event){
        alert('div2 clicked');
         event.stopPropagation(); // STOP EVENT BUBBLING
    });

    $(document).off('click', 'div#id1');
    $(document).on('click', 'div#id1', function(event){
        alert($('div#id1').find('a').attr('id'));
        $('div#id1').find('a').trigger('click');
      //  event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">DIV1
    <a href="#" id="id2">DIV2</a>
  </div>
```